# How can I group by a column but return rows with null too?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct

Let's assume following data:

| id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

I'd like to return all records where `parent_id` is either null or "distinctized":

| id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 1 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION ALL` :

```
select id, parent_id
from mytable
where parent_id is null
UNION ALL
select min(id), parent_id
from mytable
where parent_id is not null
group by parent_id
```

Result :

```
id  parent_id
1   null
2   null
3   1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/faveVK_Q)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER` + filtering:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT id, parent_id 
FROM cte
WHERE parent_id IS NULL OR rn = 1
```

**Output**:

| id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 1 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mn9LDwBDhR1SKeHNKzJKNQ/0).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `distinct on` as the following (*supposing no negative values in the id, parent_id columns*):

```
select distinct on (coalesce(parent_id, -id)) id, parent_id
from tbl_name
order by coalesce(parent_id, -id), id
```

To get the results sorted by id, we can wrap this query in a subquery and then order it as the following:

```
select id, parent_id
from(
  select distinct on (coalesce(parent_id, -id)) id, parent_id
  from tbl_name
  order by coalesce(parent_id, -id), id
) t
order by id
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0wvHqhYx)